# Data Validation in Excel through Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation

I want to set up Data Validation on a cell / row of cells so that the value in that particular cell cannot be changed but all the rest of the sheet can be edited, thus why I am not using read only.

Currently if I enter the value in the cell, go to `Data > Data Validation > Custom & enter ""`it achieves this (see screenshots https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDf48.jpg)
What I want to do is set this validation via the cell rather than manually as I plan on writing this field entry when create the excel document through my application.

I have done a lot on searching online and found methods for doing countif etc.. but nothing deal with formula entry for the Custom criteria.

Is anyone able to help?

---

Thanks for the quick reply DanB but it's not exactly what I am trying to achieve. My end goal is that my application can pass a value into the file (Column A Row 1 [If easier for formatting it can go into each row in column A which is populated but not required]) and the file will be saved locally. The user will then be entering details in Column B, C, D, E, etc... on their local machine, saving it and processing the file again. I want the application to check Row 1 Col A for the value and decide on how to process the remainder of the file based on this value (the reading the values in the file works already). Because each time my application generates a file it will be unique I want to try do the Data Validation using a formula in the cell so that I can write it using my application and not have to manually apply settings to the file. Is it possible to do this kind of validation using only formulas in the cell when populating it?

Comment: You question is still a little unclear, it sounds as though you will need to use a VB procedure to check the cells contents if you are planning on generating a custom file name from this.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest solution would be to use a Protected sheet, but only protect that Cell.

To do this, select the entire sheet, and choose Format Cells.
On the Protection tab, remove the check from Locked.

Now, select just the cell you want to protect, and lock it using the same method.  At this point, your entire sheet, except for the 1 cell should have Locked unchecked.

Now, on the review tab within Excel, choose protect Sheet, and uncheck the option to "Select Locked Cells".

Then, while the sheet is protected(you can password protect that part of it), that cell can't even be selected, yet the entire rest of the sheet can be.

Comment: Hi DanB. I added a more clear explanation of what I meant above I think. Thanks for you quick reply thou.

Comment: Signpost, could you give an example of the kind of data you want in the cell, it would help understand what you're looking for.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want the field to create a unique filename that can't be changed, so each time the file is processed, it creates a new file, is that correct?  That being the case, you could use a basic timestamp and text combo like;  =CONCATENATE("SampleFile-",TEXT(TODAY(),"MM-DD-YY"))